# better way to use in AJAX requests? $.POST or $.AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have seen many articles for making ajax requests..

most of them are using `$.AJAX` for jquery ajax posting and some of them are using `$.POST` for jquery ajax posting...

I want to know what is the best way if I want to **post** using ajax? which method makes the ajax request fast and in lightweight?

Comment: `$.post` is short-hand method for equivalent `$.ajax` that is set up for `POST`. They won't have any difference.

Comment: @nhahtdh- Yes I realized, thank you very much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.post` is a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` for `POST` requests, so no difference.

`$.ajax` is generally better to use if you need some advanced configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` is just shorthand for `$.ajax({type: 'POST'})`. It makes no difference to the speed or weight of the request, just changes the readability of your code.

Comment: @moonwave99 haha I was think that too... :O

Comment: @moonwave99 That's quite freaky!

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax({ type: 'POST' })` [[see reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)], so there is no acceptable performance improvement, but still a readability one.

Comment: so readability is the only diffrence, doesnt make any sence so I will use $.AJAX cuz it has advance configs like error handleing n stuff...thank you very much